# How do I know if sips -g failed?

Tags: shell, error-code, sips

I don't see sips to emit error codes at all:

```
$ sips main.rb -g all
/Users/nakilon/main.rb
Error: Error querying file

$ echo $?
0

$ sips main.rb -g allasdasda
/Users/nakilon/main.rb
Error: Error querying file

$ echo $?
0
```

How do I know if it has failed?

Comment: what do you get from `file $(which sips)` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, `/usr/bin/sips: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

Comment: @Nakilon I think that this is not actually a programming problem -- or rather, it is, but you've already solved the programming part of it by testing `$?`. The fact that `sips` returns 0 on failure means that it isn't playing nice, and you need to file a bug with the author of the program.

Comment: @BartonChittenden, yeah, at first I was about to ask it at AskDifferent but thought this problem was more technical. I'll repost it there if noone would share their experience here. For now I check the STDERR for emptiness.

Answer (score 0):

`sips` (as you have tagged it) is a **macOS** program for processing images at the command-line which is probably not going to want to do much with a **Ruby** program text/script.

If you really do mean to use `sips` and with a Ruby file, you need to put the flags before the filename:

```
sips -g someImage
```

Comment: You seem to answer some totally another question than what I asked.

Comment: Is `main.rb` a Ruby program, or an image?

Comment: A Ruby program.

Comment: What are you expecting an image processor to do with a Ruby program? Try running `man sips` to see the manual pages for `sips` - the Scriptable Image Processing System.